# How to get the output of system() command qt c++?

Tags: c++, qt, command, system

I want to get the output of this command for example :

```
system("dir C:\");
```

or of :

```
QProcess::execute("cmd /c dir C:\");
```

How to do that ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
QProcess process;
process.start("cmd /c dir C:\\");
process.waitForFinished(-1);
QByteArray out = process.readAllStandardOutput();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the standard output path to be a pipe which you read from, but it would be easier to use `popen()` instead of `system()`.

Since you appear to be using Windows, you would use `_popen()`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

....

FILE *fp = _popen("dir c:\", "r");
....
while (!feof(fp)) {
    ....
}
fclose(fp);
```