# How to pass a cmd-command output to a #DEFINE MACRO in QMake

Tags: c++, svn, qmake

I added a new `#DEFINE` to my ".pro" file like this:

```
#DEFINE += SVN_V
```

now I would like to pass the output of the command "svnversion -n" to this `SVN_V`, and here is what I did:

```
#DEFINE += "SVN_V = svnversion -n"
```

but the result is

> error: no such file or directory
>
> error: svnversion: no such file or directory

so, what am I missing here exactly? (Be aware I am working with Linux Ubuntu)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It could be something like that:

```
DEFINES += "SVN_V=\"\\\"$$system(svnversion -n)\\\"\""
```

`$$system()` is a qmake function to execute system command and obtain output from it.

external quotes around SVN_V... - is for qmake - it must understand that this is a single define. If `$$system()` returns space delimited string "Unknown version" you will get in result: `-DSVN="Unknown -Dversion"`.

Next quotes `\"` - to pass `$$system()` result to compiler. Without it you will get two arguments instead of one `"Unknown` and `version"`.

Double quoted quotes `\\\"` is to pass value to preprocessor. Without it value will be without quotes and recognized as int. `\\\"` will be resolved by qmake as `\"` and passed to compiler.

Comment: thank you very much for your reply. I tried your way and the output in the cmd console is:(Could not find absolute location of file "<command-line>"), note that I am getting the correct output of the svn version in my qt #defines. besides, I am confused about the use of the dollar sign!!. since we already indicating the command by using the `system()` function why do we need to reference it again using the `$$` sign .

Comment: think, something is wrong with your .pro file. Simple .pro file declaring TEMPLATE, SOURCES and that DEFINES compiles just fine without any warnings.  `$$system()` is a qmake function, all qmake functions have `$$` prefix. See qmake function reference: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmake-function-reference.html

Comment: my .pro file is fine. however, I think it is just a matter of specifying the working copy of my svn. for now, l only need what qt gives me ... but I am enable to pass the value of my "SVN_V" as string (because I am getting the value but with a letter like this "1.23M". it gives me an error that: invalid sufix "M" on integer constant. that means it read my SVN_V as integer but the M string is making problems, so, how do I fix this issue

Comment: `DEFINES += "SVN_V=\"$$system(svnversion -n)\""` -- should be fine

Comment: sorry for this mistake but the returned value is actually written like this "1:23M" (notice the colon ":", sorry it wasn't the dot) .. but again it is not working, the previous error still exists. in addition, in my call function `asd = (SVN_V)` it return this error: ("Expected ")" before ":" token)

Answer (score 0):

My cent on table:
svn info --show-item revision