# Qt Creator. Add compilation line as additional option

Tags: qt

How to add compilation line for C++ like this?

```
-D'SVN_REV="$(shell svnversion -n .)"'
```

I need to use in in Qt project. I tried to add this:

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -D'SVN_REV="$(shell svnversion -n .)"'
```

But it doesn't work at all

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/15859809/6289623

I just paste this in my Qt .pro file:

```
DEFINES += "SVN_REV=\"\\\"$$system(svnversion -n)\\\"\""
```

And then i can use SVN_REV